# Should I put next and previous buttons on a touch device

Tags: mobile, navigation

I am updating some e-learning templates to be used on touch devices. Is it necessary to keep the next/previous buttons for smaller screens or will all user assume they can swipe to next and previous slide with their finger?

Is there any disadvantage (other than screensize) to using the buttons on touchscreen?

Comment: Who is the audience of your e-learning app/site?

Comment: Well it's actually a generic template to be used for many. But it will be for professionals. Mostly sales and marketing people.

Comment: No real problem to have the two systems narrow and swipe gesture but if you only use swipe feature be sure your users can see where they are and where the go with for example dots line on the bottom and an highlight one which is the current step.  The user needs to know every time how many pages he had already read and how many he has to read to reach the end of the learning content.

Comment: Thank you @pierrelebailly I'll get some slide counter in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't assume anything especially when it comes to a tutorial app.

Some possibilities:

1. If you are worried about screen real-estate you could use arrows on the edges with lots of alpha to avoid covering essential information.
2. You could also provide a 'how to navigate' on the first page with a 'don't show this again' option
3. You could watch out for failed navigation attempts and redirect (long touches? clicks on the edges? )